# dodge intrepid 2000 electrical problems

Tags: electrical, dodge

I have a Dodge Intrepid 2000

My car was recently wrecked.The front is bent in. [image: Here is a picture of the front]

After the wreck everything electrical was still working the only thing wrong with it was the alignment belt. I had that fixed.

Now everything just quit working like first it was just the blinkers and the windshield wipers. after that it was the radio,clock,the hear/air. after that the speedometers stopped working. Now nothing electrical in my car works except the flashers and the headlights/break lights.

Comment: ALSO MY FUSES ARE FINE

Comment: "Alignment belt"???

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because of how modern cars are designed.
Something happened. I'd honestly say take this to a shop, but a few things to check around for are:

1. Battery terminals and wires
2. Check the fusebox connections
3. Check all the wiring

Something went haywire and may be too difficult to diagnose by yourself.